# Unable to debug simple C++ program with lldb and VSCode

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, lldb

I am trying to set up a C++ debugger with lldb and VSCode on MacOS Catalina. I am able to successfully compile my source to output the executable and the .dSYM file and launch the debugger all through the VSCode launch.json and tasks.json files. I am, however, unable to set breakpoints in my editor and have them reflected in the debugger window. The program just runs all the way though.

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ build and debug ARMsim",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "ARMsim",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "g++ build ARMsim"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build ARMsim",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/ARMsim.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/ARMsim"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Program source code, note breakpoints on lines 9 and 10.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHuzN.png)

[Debugger window text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGWYi.png)

My only thought is that this has something to do with the .dSYM file. Either my breakpoints are not being reflected in it, or it isn't being loaded into lldb, or I am misinterpreting how this all works. I have seen the other StackOverflow posts about this issue, but I am indeed compiling with the -g flag and my symbols file is being created.

Answer (score 0):

Small note, you were able to set breakpoints.

What got it working for me was that the program item in launch.json needs to look like this:
`"program": "${workspaceFolder}/ARMsim"`

Without a fully qualified path, I get an error and can't actually debug anything.

With only that change, my debugger starts, an external terminal window is opened, the source file is made active, and I am stopped at the first line of the main function (because of stopAtEntry being true). Continuing stops at the breakpoint.

The only other thing I can think of is making sure that you always open folders in VS Code, never individual files. Otherwise VS Code wont' know what the workspace folder is.

I am assuming that everything else is set up and working properly. XCode command line tools, proper extensions, etc. And if you haven't replaced the stock g++ (which I don't recommend at all), you're really just invoking clang++.

And one other small note. You don't have to convert your filename to a C-string as of C++11.

Comment: I made that change, and unfortunately it still isnt working.

I launch VS Code by navigating to the directory from the terminal and using "code ." so that shouldn't be an issue.

I have XCode command line tools installed, and am using the Microsoft "C/C++" Intellisence, debugging, and code browsing extension. I also have "Code Runner" extension, but to be honest don't really know which extensions I should be using.

Comment: Another question, what does it matter if I am invoking clang++ instead of g++? After some digging in my usr/bin, I'm fairly certain that is happening.

Comment: I can't speculate as to what else is not set up or configured properly, unfortunately. I might recommend nuking your existing json files and having VS Code re-generate them for you. The 'do X on active file' versions are pretty good, you just have to make sure the file you want to debug is currently active. You can easily verify your compiler with `g++ --version`. I added that as more of a heads up. For example, I had to constantly tell students to test their code with the lab compiler because I didn't care if it compiled on their machine. It needed to compile on the lab to be graded.

Comment: I did my testing on latest VS Code on MBP running Mojave. If XCode has updated recently, you need to open it so it can configure stuff.